# Translation involving nuances of 、 and へ

Tags: grammar, translation, phrases, particle-へ

I am working on translating the phrase 格闘の天才、世界へ. All available information tells me that the translation should be either "Fighting geniuses to the world" or "Fighting geniuses, to the world". However, neither of these translations make much sense; I'm guessing that I'm missing some nuance here. I have a feeling that "Fighting geniuses, into the world" might make a little more sense, but doesn't appear to be accurate.

I believe the issue relates to a lack of understanding of the comma in Japanese grammar, and possibly missing some nuances of the へ particle.

Can someone please help me understand these nuances better and get a more natural translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulties may be (1) the language of article headline and (2) the meaning of 世界, but not much about the comma.

As for (2) 世界 can mean *the international arena of activity* as opposed to the domestic. Since it is about a fighter here, it means the international competition. As another example, 世界のX where X is some product means *X as a internationally well-known product* (or something along these lines).

The phrase X, Yへ in a headline means some movement (possibly figurative) of X to Y. [This paper (pages 55+)](https://www.kansaigaidai.ac.jp/common/pdf/info.disclosure.theses.ko61_dissertation.pdf) has a variety of examples. For example, 海自 災害訓練南シナ海へ means *Maritime SDF going to the South China Sea for Emergency Drill*.

Another small thing is that Xの天才 means *a genius of X*. It might depend on contexts, but at least the phrase in question should be about a singular genius of fighting.

So the whole phrase means *A very promising fighter (who has been fighting only domestically until now) is going to fight in international competitions (or world championship or something)*.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, the Yへ could, in some contexts (like this one), be considered as a short-hand version of Yへ行きます (The only term I've learned so far) or similar. Would that be accurate?

Comment: @BenJaguarMarshall Yes, like the SDF example. But something going to somewhere tends not to be news-worthy and literal meaning is less likely in headlines. In conversations, there are cases of simple omissions such as 買い物へ  as a response to *where  are you going?*.